# grant read/write access to read only user for only one schema PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have a user, who has read access to all the schema. I want to extend his access to create, insert, update and select for only one schema, is there a way.

I tried like

```
 ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user_rd IN SCHEMA schema_name
       GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO user_rd;
```

But, not working.

Please help.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command only affects future tables created by `user_rd`. You need to use the role that will run the `CREATE TABLE` statement instead. And no, there is no command to alter default privileges on tables created by *any* user.

Answer (score 0):

The default works for new tables that you create in the future. For existing tables, you have to use a different command:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name 
TO user_rd;
```